# Textbox and serialPort.Write() not work in C#

Tags: c#, .net, timer, textbox, serial-port

I have an application that writes data to a serial port and something strange is happening.
If I write it directly follows it works:

```
SerialPort.Write ("at\r\n");
```

If I get the code from a textbox, it does not work

```
String command = txtCommand.Text.Trim();
sp.Write (command);
```

Already took a MessageBox.Show (command), and the value is correct!
What is happening?

Comment: Did you try to append the new line and linefeed to the TextBox's Text?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not. Give me an example, please?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
serialPort.Write(textBox1.text + "\r\n");
```

Comment: Good! Then you can replace textBox1.text with your text string.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, obviously the guy was looking for a piece of code otherwise he could have solved it on his own. However, pleasure. You got the plus on your comment.